# How to check if JSON is contain in an array JSON objects in golang

Tags: json, go

I have an array of JSON objects as

Structs:

```
type Data struct {
    TaiList []Tai `json:"taiList"`
}

type Tai struct {
    PlmnId *PlmnId `json:"plmnId"`

    Tac string `json:"tac"`

    Nid string `json:"nid"`
}

type PlmnId struct {
    Mcc string `json:"mcc"`

    Mnc string `json:"mnc"`
}
```

The JSON in mongodb is of the form

```
[
{
    "taiList": [
          {
            "plmnId": {
                "mcc": "244",
                "mnc": "24"
            },
            "tac": "00001",
            "nid": "99"
        },
        {
            "plmnId": {
                "mcc": "244",
                "mnc": "34"
            },
            "tac": "00001",
            "nid": "555"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "taiList": [
       {
        "plmnId": {
            "mcc": "244",
            "mnc": "24"
        },
        "tac": "00001",
        "nid": "99"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

The JSON "taiList" is formed after the unmarhsal from mongodb, error check intentionally omitted.

```
func MongoFind(id string) (Data, error) {

    filter := bson.M{"_id": id}
    var (
        result model.Data

    )
    ...
    DB.Collection(tailistCollection).FindOne(context.TODO(),filter).Decode(&result)
    ...
    return result, nil
}
```

The MongoFind returns Data and error. The Data.TaiList array is what i would like to perform the check.

I would like to check if the JSON object "ta" is contain in the "taiList".

```
 var ta = model.Tai{
    PlmnId: &model.PlmnId{Mcc: "244", Mnc: "34"},
    Tac:    "00001",
    Nid:    "555",
}
```

I tried with the code below

```
var data Data

func CheckTai(ta models.Tai, data Data) bool {
    for _, Tai := range data.TaiList {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(Tai, ta) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

but CheckTai function return false.
The CheckTai only return true when there is only one JSON object that match the list as

```
{
      "taiList": [
        {
          "plmnId": {
            "mcc": "244",
            "mnc": "24"
          },
          "tac": "00001",
          "nid": "555"
        }

      ]
    }
```

Need help or idea on how to perform this check.

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mcve].   We cannot see the call to CheckTai or the unmarshal code.

Comment: The code with example data works as expected in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lgpoH0eSa54

Comment: Sorry i did not frame the question well but I would like to perform the check on an array of "taiList". I have edited the array and the the check on this array of "taiList" return false unless there is only one JSON object of the "taiList" in the array, in that case it works. I expect in the given array, the return value should be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from comments I replicated your scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Data struct {
    TaiList []Tai `json:"taiList"`
}

type Tai struct {
    PlmnId *PlmnId `json:"plmnId"`

    Tac string `json:"tac"`

    Nid string `json:"nid"`
}

type PlmnId struct {
    Mcc string `json:"mcc"`

    Mnc string `json:"mnc"`
}

var data = []byte(`{
    "taiList": [
      {
        "plmnId": {
            "mcc": "244",
            "mnc": "24"
        },
        "tac": "00001",
        "nid": "99"
        },
        {
        "plmnId": {
            "mcc": "244",
            "mnc": "34"
        },
        "tac": "00001",
        "nid": "555"
        }
    ]
}
`)

var ta = Tai{
    PlmnId: &PlmnId{Mcc: "244", Mnc: "34"},
    Tac:    "00001",
    Nid:    "555",
}

func CheckTai(ta Tai, data Data) bool {
    for _, Tai := range data.TaiList {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(Tai, ta) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    var v Data
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(CheckTai(ta, v))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```